# Show all x-axis markers for Numbers' bar graphs

Tags: numbers, iwork

With Numbers' bar graph, I'd like to show **all** x-axis markers of my table, or at least selected few with all the columns present.

but only a few is displayed when there are many. The only way to show more is to drag to enlarge the chart, but this makes the chart unreadable if I attach it in a post.

How to I achieve what I want without resizing the graph or cut down my data columns?

Answer (score 1):

Select the chart, then in the Format inspector, choose Axis → Category (X) and under Category Labels choose **Show All Category Labels**.

[image]

All the columns are always present in the graph regardless of this option, however they will be unlabelled.